# nginx settings are correct but fails to proxy: logs show zero error/activity

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have a domain that would hit my nginx proxy to be routed to their nodejs hosted site locally on a different port. About a month ago it stopped working:

DNS A records are fine and forward to correct IP
Website works if I go to ip address with correct port(3100)
Hell, it even works if I type domain.com:3100.
It's an Ec2 instance and port is open to all IP addresses

Here are the config file in the sites-enabled/site-available folder:

```
server {
listen  80;
server_name www.cpcarpet.com cpcarpet.com;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/cpcarpetaccess.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/cpcarpeterror.error.log debug;

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3100/;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I've restarted the nginx service quite a bit and updated the package but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

So to clarify what does work:

IP address:3100 works! Ok!

cpcarpet.com:3100 works!(So A records are set correctly) Works! Ok!

www.cpcarpet.com or cpcarpet.com? Does not work! Log files show no access/errors either.

Comment: did you look in log files? may be there is some clue

Comment: Try to change localhost to actual IP -> 127.0.0.1:3100

Comment: @aarosil log files aren't showing anything(empty) which is odd. If I connect with the port directly, the general access logs show successful activity or errors to that node application. It's like my proxy is being completely bypassed.

Comment: @Molda tried that right now, didn't work.

Comment: set verbose logging in nginx, it should at least log something when it starts. probably this is some easily overlooked but critical detail

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this helps you.

```
 server {
   listen 80;

   server_name cpcarpet.com;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3100;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```